# Django + Python: Will type automatically detected right?

Tags: python

I wonder if I have to convert `discount_value` into a decimal (to make sure). It seems when I test it with `print` discount_value it's type is automatically detected as a decimal. However, I had cases before, where it was detected as a float and didn't work anymore.

```
def calculate_discounted_value(self, ticket_price_gross):
        [...]

        elif self.percentage:
            discount_value = Decimal(ticket_price_gross * self.percentage)
            discount_value = quantize(discount_value, '1')
            print(ticket_price_gross - discount_value, "PERCENTAGE")

def quantize(amount, decimals):
    """
    Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and
    2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users
    typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it
    does with binary floating point. With this function we get better control about
    rounding.

    Therefore: amount should be come in as decimal.
    """
    #amount_as_decimal = Decimal(amount)
    amount_as_decimal = amount
    quantized_amount = amount_as_decimal.quantize(
        Decimal(decimals),
        rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP
    )
    return quantized_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unnecessary to to make `discount_value` a `Decimal()` before passing it to `quantize()` since `quantize` converts to `Decimal()`. For the same reason, the commented line seems unnecessary, but so does your whole `quantize()` function. Why not just do this?

```
def calculate_discounted_value(self, ticket_price_gross):
        [...]

        elif self.percentage:
            discount_value = Decimal(ticket_price_gross * self.percentage).quantize(Decimal(1), rounding='ROUND_HALF_UP')
            print(ticket_price_gross - discount_value, "PERCENTAGE")
```

Also note [this](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) about `quantize()`:

> Unlike other operations, if the length of the coefficient after the
>   quantize operation would be greater than precision, then an
>   InvalidOperation is signaled. This guarantees that, unless there is an
>   error condition, the quantized exponent is always equal to that of the
>   right-hand operand.